# Convert mysql query to its equivalent Knex query

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to convert my mysql query to its equivalent Knex query

Here is the query
`CREATE TABLE test ( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100), unique (id) ) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;`

So basically I want to create a table with a column named "id" of type auto increment whose value starts from 1001.

I want it's equivalent Knex query. Tried surfing through documentation but couldn't get much help.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Knex.js Schema from SQL is like** :

```
knex.schema.createTable('test', function(table) {
  table.increments('id').unsigned().notNullable().unique().defaultTo(1001);
  table.string('name', 100);
})
```

Comment: Thanks buddy ! It worked. Could you let me know few resources to learn knex.

Comment: It's official documentation. I have done this query based on knex documentation.

Comment: If this answer is good for your question then you can mark as right and upvote it for others users. Cheers!